# Given $n$, find $a,b$ such that $a+b=n$ and $\Omega(a)+\Omega(b)$ is maximized

Tags: prime-numbers, special-functions, puzzle, prime-factorization

Given a number $n$, find $a,b$ such that:

1. $a,b$ non-negative integers
2. $a+b=n$
3. $\Omega(a)+\Omega(b)$ is maximized

> [$\Omega(n)$](http://oeis.org/wiki/Omega(n),_number_of_prime_factors_of_n_(with_multiplicity)) counts the number of prime factors of n (with multiplicity).
>
> For example, for $n = 44100 = 2^2 3^2 5^2 7^2$, we have $\Omega(44100)
> = \Omega(2^2 3^2 5^2 7^2) = 8$, as the eight prime factors (with repetition) of $n$, are 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7, and 7. Obviously $\Omega(1) = 0 $, since 1 is the product of no primes, and for $ p$ prime we have $\Omega(p) = 1 $, since a prime has only one prime factor (itself).

With most of the numbers there are more than one pair of $a$ and $b$ with the same maximal result. With many numbers the highest result achieved by setting $a$ to the highest power of $2$ that is smaller than $n$, but there are also many other cases such as:

$
17=8+9 \rightarrow 5 \\
33=9+24 \rightarrow 6 \\
34=16+18 \rightarrow 7 \\
43=16+27 \rightarrow 7 \\
51=24+27 \rightarrow 7 \\
61=16+45 \rightarrow 7 \\
66=18+48 \rightarrow 8 \\
68=32+36 \rightarrow 9 \\
77=32+45 \rightarrow 8 \\
$

Is there a general rule how to find a pair that will achieve the highest result?